# How to remove, order up, down elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, dom-events

I'm using JavaScript to remove, order up, order down a text row, it runs normally in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox.

When I run, I received a message from console bug:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

How to fix the error?

```js
function dels(index) {
  var frm = document.writeForm;
  var opts = frm['ans' + index].value = ''; // eval("frm.ans_list" + index + ".options"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    if (opts[i].selected) {
      opts[i--].removeChild(true);
    }
  }
  eval("frm.ans" + index + ".value = '' ");
  setting_val(index);
}

function up_move(index) {
  var frm = document.writeForm;
  var opts = eval("frm.ans_list" + index + ".options"); // frm['ans' + index].value = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i > 0) {
      tmp = opts[i].cloneNode(true);
      opts[i].removeChild(true);
      opts[i - 1].insertAdjacentElement("beforeBegin", tmp).selected = true;
    }
  }

  setting_val(index);
}
**(UPDATED)**
function down_move(index)
{
var frm = document.writeForm;
var opts=frm["ans_list" + index].options            // eval("frm.ans_list" + index + ".options");   // frm['ans' + index].value = '';

for (var i=opts.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i<opts.length-1) {
        tmp = opts[i].cloneNode(true);
        opts[i].removeChild(true);
        opts[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd", tmp).selected = true;
    }
}

 setting_val(index);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="javasript:dels('<%=i+1%>',document.writeForm.ans<%=i+1%>.value);" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">Delete</span></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javasript:up_move('<%=i+1%>');" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">▲ Order</span></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javasript:down_move('<%=i+1%>');" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">▼ Order</span></a>
```

Comment: Firstly remove the javasript: label - it is misspelled and unnecessary. Then post a [mcve] using the rendered HTML since it is not a PHP issue and you have PHP tags. Include rendered HTML of your table. Lastly have a search for textnodes firefox

Comment: Secondly, remove the evals, they really are not needed, and are probably the reason for the error. Use dynamic property names instead.

Comment: Jus a side note: if you access dynamic key in object you can use `frm["ans_list" + index].options` without eval, eval is not good idea here.

Comment: and to remove node from DOM you need to call it on parent and pass object `var node = opts[i--]; node.parentElement.removeChild(node);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Comment: Thank you, I have updated and down_move() and up_move() have happened same error... :(

Comment: You still have a boolean as a parameter for `removeChild`, please re-read Kulvar's answer and the linked documentation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong use of removeChild

```
if (opts[i].selected) {
  opts[i--].removeChild(true);
}
```

The function is intended as:

```
ParentNode.removeChild(ChildNode);
// OR
ChildNode.parentNode.removeChild(ChildNode);
```

[MDN Documentation on removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

Also, you can replace all your evals

```
eval("frm.ans" + index + ".value = '' ")
eval("frm.ans_list" + index + ".options")
```

It would be better written as

```
frm["ans" + index].value = ""
frm["ans_list" + index].options
```

Finally,

```
tmp = opts[i].cloneNode(true);
opts[i].removeChild(true);
opts[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd", tmp).selected = true;
```

Cloning a node, appending the clone, and removing the original would be optimized as moving the original to its new location.
But, you try to remove the original, then insert the clone after the original. It's odd.

If I correctly understood what you try to do, this function could help you.

```
function reverse_options_order(select_element)
{
    // we store the current value to restore it after reordering
    const selected_value = select_element.value;
    // document fragment will temporarily hold the children
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while (select_element.lastChild)
    {
        // last child become first child, effectively reversing the order
        fragment.appendChild(select_element.lastChild);
    }
    // appending a fragment is equal to appending all its children
    // the fragment will "merge" with the select_element seamlessly
    select_element.appendChild(fragment);
    select_element.value = selected_value;
}
```

You can use the same method to reverse any nodes order

Comment: Could you provide the updated version of your code? It would help knowing where the error come from now that you modified the code.

Comment: Hi @Kulvar: I see it seem has happen at line: opts[i].removeChild(true);   in down_move and up_move()

Comment: You're still trying to append the cloned element to the DOM removed original element. And it's still not `removeChild(true)`

Comment: Hi @Kulvar: can you modify and update in your answer ?